# Where can I get a version of Pax Imperia for Windows?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, pax-imperia

Back in the old days I used to have *Pax Imperia* on an old Mac. That game was awesome, but I've not been able to find a version of it for Windows. Does anyone know if there is a version of it available?

I'm talkin' about the old *Pax Imperia*, not *Pax Imperia 2*.

Answer (score 3):

*Pax Imperia* was never released for Windows; it was a Macintosh exclusive.  Its sequel (*Pax Imperia: Eminent Domain*) was, however, and is usually considered [abandonware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware).

As the original game was for Macintosh OS 7, it is unlikely that it was ever ported to another platform. I'm sorry.

Comment: You're killin' me, you're really killin' me. :(

Comment: I remember that game, and loved it.  So simple!

Answer (score 2):

While you may not be able to get a copy for Windows, if you still have your Mac copy available, it may run in [SheepSaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net/), the Mac OS 9 emulator. Given the age of the game (and thus, the unlikelihood of requiring advanced graphics support), it should run fairly well on modern PC hardware in emulation.

I've used SheepSaver in the past, on prior PCs, and found it pretty reliable and workable. (Unlike, say, Executor.)

If you act quickly, you might even be able to purchase a new copy of the game itself on [eBay](http://cgi.ebay.com/Pax-Imperia-MAC-CD-trading-diplomacy-combat-game-/250558029252?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a566c1dc4).